# Displacement of the inner table's values

Tags: html, html-table

My HTML page has table and 2 inner tables inside as `td` inside `tr`. The problem I have encountered is displacement in a case when values in two tables are different in terms of characters value. Here's my page:

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<table>

<tr>
<td>1st input field</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table style="width: 100%">

<tr>
<td>All:</td>
<td>500</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part1:</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part2:</td>
<td>140</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part3:</td>
<td>260</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2nd input field</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table style="width: 100%">

<tr>
<td>All:</td>
<td>700</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part1:</td>
<td>200</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part2:</td>
<td>200</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part3:</td>
<td>300</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Now let's say that inside 1st inner table property all has 7 chars:

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<table>

<tr>
<td>1st input field</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table style="width: 100%">

<tr>
<td>All:</td>
<td>500.123</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part1:</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part2:</td>
<td>140</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part3:</td>
<td>260</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2nd input field</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<table style="width: 100%">

<tr>
<td>All:</td>
<td>700</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part1:</td>
<td>200</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part2:</td>
<td>200</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>part3:</td>
<td>300</td>
<td>$</td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Thankfully, every value from the first table "went" to the left, but in the 2nd table values remain still on its positions. How can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I needed to redesign your codes, I removed the child tables and added `colspan` to the **header**. Although I'm not sure why you needed to use another table as children.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">1st input field</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <tr>
        <td>All:</td>
        <td>500.123</td>
        <td>$</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>part1:</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>$</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>part2:</td>
        <td>140</td>
        <td>$</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>part3:</td>
        <td>260</td>
        <td>$</td>
      </tr>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">2nd input field</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <tr>
        <td>All:</td>
        <td>700</td>
        <td>$</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>part1:</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>$</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>part2:</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>$</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>part3:</td>
        <td>300</td>
        <td>$</td>
      </tr>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason here is you have not set sizes for table cells. Cell with number `500.123` in it has more width, so the column becomes much wider, then in the second table. You can solve the problem by using simple `CSS`, just set some classes and then set them certain width.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tr td:first-child {
  width: 40px;
}

tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <table>

    <tr>
      <td>1st input field</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="width: 100%">

          <tr>
            <td>All:</td>
            <td>500.123</td>
            <td>$</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>part1:</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>$</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>part2:</td>
            <td>140</td>
            <td>$</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>part3:</td>
            <td>260</td>
            <td>$</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>2nd input field</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <table style="width: 100%;">

          <tr>
            <td>All:</td>
            <td>700</td>
            <td>$</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>part1:</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>$</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>part2:</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>$</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>part3:</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>$</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```